# Can I embed a Tab View Controller into a container view?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

If this is possible how would I do it? Preferably using storyboards

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

1. Add a Container View in View Controller.
2. Delete the default View linked with the Container View.
3. Add a Tab View Controller into the Storyboard.
4. Now link Container View with the Tab Controller. `right-click -> drag -> embed`.

Comment: Thanks,  the rest of the views connected don't adapt and work now though. Essentially a button doesn't work

Comment: To clarify Step 4: you have to right-click and drag the container to the tab bar controller. If you drag the tab bar controller to the container, the Embed option doesn't appear.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer and I have query Bista how can I give IBOutlet connection for the Tab Controller(Because it is in container view)?

Comment: @user3182143 - haven't tried, but you can create a custom class of Container view and assign that class to your UI Container view and from there I think you can go and make connections.